# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\\3^x}{x^2}\mathrm dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I don't know how to evaluate this integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\\3^x}{x^2}\mathrm dx $$

Could you give me advice on how I can do it because I am actually puzzled?

I tried to integrate by parts, but in finally, I had the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} {e^x\ln x}dx $$

I didn't know how to evaluate it too.

Comment: Sorry for my English in advance.

Comment: The integral diverges.

Comment: could you explain how you detected it?

Comment: In the same way as WillM's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $3^x \geq 1$ for $x$ between zero and $1$ and since $\int x^{-2} dx = -x^{-1},$ it follow that the integral is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

[Sagecell.sagemath.org](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) can do integrals for you. entering in the code:

`var('y')`

`y = 3^x/x^2`

`integral(y, x, 0, 1)`

returns the error:

`ValueError: Integral is divergent.`

Comment: Although this answer is technically correct, I th
ink that this is a *really bad* way for a student to approach this problem.

Comment: @T. Bongers: Im not suggesting that knowing the answer is sufficient. For someone struggling to formulate a plan of attack, it does help to know if they should be searching for a positive or negative result.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't this be more appropriate as a comment than an answer?